# Maas isn't showing Trusty as a deployable Distro

Tags: 14.04, maas

I am running MAAS 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.3. I added the trusty OS to /etc/maas/import_pxe_files (RELEASES="precise raring trusty"
).

I ran the maas-import-pxe-files script and it seemed to have downloaded Trusty, but I am not seeing it in the as a deployable release. Is there anywhere else I need to set this? or is Trusty downloading as an RC (or something similar) and MAAS isn't willing to deploy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow later versions of Ubuntu to show up in MAAS <= 1.4 you would need to edit the file /usr/share/pyshared/maasserver/enum.py to add the new release names to the MAAS web UI.

For example, you would need to change the DISTRO_SERIES class as follows:

```
class DISTRO_SERIES:
    """List of supported ubuntu releases."""
    #:
    default = ''
    #:
    precise = 'precise'
    #:
    quantal = 'quantal'
    #:
    raring = 'raring'
    #:
    saucy = 'saucy'
    #:
    trusty = 'trusty'

DISTRO_SERIES_CHOICES = (
    (DISTRO_SERIES.default, 'Default Ubuntu Release'),
    (DISTRO_SERIES.precise, 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "Precise Pangolin"'),
    (DISTRO_SERIES.quantal, 'Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal"'),
    (DISTRO_SERIES.raring, 'Ubuntu 13.04 "Raring Ringtail"'),
    (DISTRO_SERIES.saucy, 'Ubuntu 13.10 "Saucy Salamander"'),
    (DISTRO_SERIES.trusty, 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr"'),
)
```

You do have to make sure you have also downloaded the boot images into /var/lib/maas/ephemeral/ so they are available.
But then you should be able to select each version from the MAAS web ui as a deployment target.

If you are using Juju to deploy, then make sure you also update your environments.yaml file's default-series parameter to select the series you want to deploy.

Comment: Sadly I can't upvote yet. But this is the exact answer I needed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing further documentation for 1.3 I see that Trusty may not be supported: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.3/_autosummary/maasserver.enum.html#module-maasserver.enum